Not enough room for water stop valve below kitchen sink
I'm updating some of the piping below my kitchen sink and trying to understand options to repair a water stop valve that was broken when we moved in. The stop valve's wheel was separated and laying on top of the pipe underneath it. The wheel doesn't seem re-attachable because of how close the two pipes are.
Is there an obvious way to remediate this? As it stands, the only way I can shut off cold water to this faucet is by fully shutting off the water for my residence. It would be nice to have the option to shut it off from this valve.



There are a few options here:
You could cut the copper supply pipe and add a 90 or 45 deg. elbow to raise the valve away from the drain.
You can replace the valve with a 90 deg. 1/4 turn valve.
OR; just use a pair of pliers to turn the shaft of the old valve to shut it off and turn it on.  This is something that is not done often, so it is a minor inconvenience.
